# Migrating a project or Creating a new one

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a application, where it was developed using Asp.NET MVC 3 and .net framework 4.0. I am using Visual Studio 2017. I am facing following problems.

1. Whenever I try to add controller, by right clicking it. Add scaffolding window is not popping up.
2. Even if I try to add it by adding class and change everything manually, it shows errors.
3. Whenever I try above steps to add controller or model, it gives some new errors.

Do I need to upgrade the project to latest version of MVC and .net framework?
As error says there is error in assembly reference.
What I need to do because, VS2017 has .net framework 4.5 and asp.net mvc 5.
 I tried by Google solutions, but all the existing files vanished from the solution explorer.
What do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not create new project instead just take a backup of you current project and try to upgrade to MVC 5. There is nice [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-migrate-mvc-3-application-to-mvc-5) to migrate MVC3 project to MVC5. Just try to migrate the project.